# Using a Combobox to fill in a Text Field in Scribus

Tags: javascript, combobox, acrobat

I'm building a PDF in Scribus and stumbling through javascript (basic newbie here) as I go. I've ran into an issue and I can't seem to find a good answer.

I have a combobox called productType where a user selects a product. Once they do that I want a text field called mortClause to display the proper clause. I've placed the following code under the combobox's Action -> On Blur -> Javascript.

Here is what I have that is not working:

```
var ckSelect = this.getField("productType");
var ckResult = this.getField("mortClause");

if (ckSelect.value === "VA") {
   mortClause.value = 'VA Clause';
} else if (ckSelect.value === "FHA") {
   mortClause.value = 'FHA Clause';
} else {
   mortClause.value = 'Normal Clause';
}
```

Comment: Is no one answering because I put this question in the wrong place, or because the code is sound so it should be working?

Answer (score 0):

"mortClause" is not the name of your variable, its ckResult.

If you change

```
mortClause.value = 'VA Clause';
```

to

```
ckResult.value = 'VA Clause';
```

you get the expected behaviour.

But you probably already know that. or gave up, after 3 years.